# How do I use custom env vars running vercel cli on github action?

Tags: deployment, next.js, environment-variables, github-actions, vercel

#### Goal:

I have an API that changes the URL based on the brach name and in my front-end (nextjs -> vercel) I want to reference the API URL on the github actions file.

#### Problem:

Vercel has only 3 environments where I can put variables *preview*, *development* and *production* therefore the variables are shared among deploys that uses the same environment, since my variable changes over time I want to pass its value on deploy/build step but the [vercel CLI](https://vercel.com/docs/cli) keeps using the preview environment despite my efforts of using `--build-env` and `--env` flags

### Current run

#### main steps:

1. Save the branch name on `$GITHUB_ENV`

   ```
    yaml
    # github-action.yaml
    name: Vercel Preview Release
    env:
      BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}
    ...
   ```
2. Reconstruct API URL base on brach name and other vars

   ```
    - name: reconstruct API URL and HASH_ID_SEED
      run: |
        NAME=$BRANCH_NAME
        NNAME="${NAME////-}"
        MNAME="${NNAME//./-}"
        echo "NEXT_PUBLIC_HASH_ID_SEED=$MNAME" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
        echo "NEXT_PUBLIC_API_LINK=https://$PROJECT_NAME-$MNAME-api-$API_LINK_END"
   ```
3. deploy using `NEXT_PUBLIC_API_LINK` and other vars

   ```
    - name: Deploy Project Artifacts to Vercel
      run: >- 
        vercel deploy
        -b NEXT_PUBLIC_HASH_ID_SEED=$NEXT_PUBLIC_HASH_ID_SEED
        -b NEXTAUTH_SECRET=$NEXTAUTH_SECRET
        -b NEXT_PUBLIC_API_LINK=$NEXT_PUBLIC_API_LINK
        -e NEXT_PUBLIC_HASH_ID_SEED=$NEXT_PUBLIC_HASH_ID_SEED
        -e NEXTAUTH_SECRET=$NEXTAUTH_SECRET
        -e NEXT_PUBLIC_API_LINK=$NEXT_PUBLIC_API_LINK
        --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
   ```

#### Result:

Give no errors,
generates a brand new deploy link,
**but** the app call the wrong api link,
[image: wrong api link]

#### Other informations:

- All the tutorials about vercel deploy that I read said to execute three commands in a row: `vercel pull [environment] --token=<token>` than `vercel build --token=<token>` and `vercel deploy --prebuilt --token=<token>` 
   There are a few problems with this:

  1. I can not change the env vars since it **pulls** from one of the default vercel environments
  2. The file `./.vercel/.env.preview.local` comes with a var `VERCEL_URL=""` which causes conflict with `next-auth`
- the build step seems like is not required, I did some runs without it and deployed with no errors, again the app was calling the wrong API
- Entire github action file:

```yaml
name: Vercel Preview Release
env:
  BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}
  VERCEL_ORG_ID: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_ORG_ID }}
  VERCEL_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_PROJECT_ID }}
  VERCEL_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}

  PROJECT_NAME: ${{ secrets.PROJECT_NAME }}
  NEXTAUTH_SECRET: ${{ secrets.NEXTAUTH_SECRET }}
  API_LINK_END: ${{ secrets.API_LINK_END }}
  
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - release-*
      - release/*

jobs:
  Deploy-Preview:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - name: reconstruct API URL and HASH_ID_SEED
        run: |
          NAME=$BRANCH_NAME
          NNAME="${NAME////-}"
          MNAME="${NNAME//./-}"
          echo "NEXT_PUBLIC_HASH_ID_SEED=$MNAME" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
          echo "NEXT_PUBLIC_API_LINK=https://$PROJECT_NAME-$MNAME-api-$API_LINK_END"
      - name: Install Vercel CLI
        run: npm install --global vercel@latest --immutable
      - name: Deploy Project Artifacts to Vercel
          run: >- 
            vercel deploy
            -b NEXT_PUBLIC_HASH_ID_SEED=$NEXT_PUBLIC_HASH_ID_SEED
            -b NEXTAUTH_SECRET=$NEXTAUTH_SECRET
            -b NEXT_PUBLIC_API_LINK=$NEXT_PUBLIC_API_LINK
            -e NEXT_PUBLIC_HASH_ID_SEED=$NEXT_PUBLIC_HASH_ID_SEED
            -e NEXTAUTH_SECRET=$NEXTAUTH_SECRET
            -e NEXT_PUBLIC_API_LINK=$NEXT_PUBLIC_API_LINK
            --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
```

### Expectations:

Run deploy command with env vars arguments that are actually used on the final app

Comment: This link can be helpful https://github.com/neondatabase/preview-branches-with-vercel/blob/main/.github/workflows/deploy-preview.yml